# Replace content of the line (in ace.editor) and overwrite it

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I have some Content in an ace.editor. and now i have an Trigger-Button which puts new text in that actual line - this works, but i want to overwrite the complete content in line (filled with Tabs and numbers) like this:

[image]

That line, where the Cursor has his actual possition should be overrited complete and filled with new Content. with my code (see below) i can write in the Editor but it will not overwrite it.

See my code, like i tryed:

```
function Textuebergabe_NP01(text) {
    null_tabelle_dues1_text.insert(
       null_tabelle_dues1_text.replace(/^.*,\s*RA:\s*/, "") + text + '\r\n    '
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace contents of a line use `editor.session.replace` function.
like this

```
var Range = require("ace/range").Range
var row = editor.selection.lead.row
var newText = "someText"
editor.session.replace(new Range(row, 0, row, Number.MAX_VALUE), newText)
```

Comment: @a user, thanks at first. this is working. but i have now an additional Problem. i have more Editors, and i want to put those values in a <pre id="null_tabelle_dues1_text">. i could not figure it out how to put all there. here my code with your function:>>>>>> function readAbsAxforNp01() {
 var Range = require("ace/range").Range
 var row = editor.selection.lead.row
 var newNP01data = ("  " + paramXabs + "  " + paramYabs + "  " + paramZabs);
 document.innerHTML(null_tabelle_dues1_text) = editor.session.replace(new Range(row, 0, row, Number.MAX_VALUE), newNP01data)
}

Comment: Sorry, what you wrote doesn't make any sense.  
`document.innerHTML(null_tabelle_dues1_text)` what are you trying to do? innerHTML isn't a function! `= editor.session.replace` `editor.session.replace` doesn't return a string.

Comment: My 2.nd editor is in the pre I'd null_tabelle_dues1_text. I tried to put it in there. I think also, that is not running like that, when I send the text via InnerHTML it will put the desired text to the editor with the id null_tabelle_... Now, with your function it puts the text in the main editor..  How I can send it to the other?

Comment: you can't set editor value with innerHTML, maybe you are looking for editor.setValue?

Comment: The editor is new for me. I have one main editor,  but there the data which I want to send don't have to be imported. And I have 4 other editor.  and those I show in my html file via <pre id="null_tabelle_..."></Pre>. When I'm using InnerHTML I could send the data in the 2nd editor but the line will not be overridden.  With your code it will be, but only in the main editor and there's not needed.  sorry it's a little bit heavy to explain.  If you want more details I can send you a bigger mal with picture explains

Comment: If it takes a bigger mail to explain, you'd better create another question, and maybe add a link to your site or to jsbin example. Comments provide too small room, for that. Anyway code snippet you show `document.innerHTML(null_tabelle_dues1_text) = ...` wasn't present in original question, and is invalid javascript! One can't doo `f() = 1` in js.

Comment: THATS IT! i have to name in your code the ID of my <pre> name. this works: function readAbsAxforNp01() {
 var Range = require("ace/range").Range
 var row = null_tabelle_dues1_text.selection.lead.row
 var newNP01data = ("  " + paramXabs + "  " + paramYabs + "  " + paramZabs);
 null_tabelle_dues1_text.session.replace(new Range(row, 0, row, Number.MAX_VALUE), newNP01data)}

Comment: You can use Infinity instead of Number.MAX_VALUE.